# Read excel cell values containing formulae with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I am trying to read an excel with pandas but because it has formulae it will return nan values when reading it instead of the cell values.

```
df=pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: What values do you have in Excel itself? Pandas will return results of the calculations stored in the saved file. If saved file has mistakes and have #VALUE!, then pandas will read NaN for those cells.

Comment: The formulae will give me number values, no errors, and return nan when trying to read it directly using pandas

Comment: Very strange, it definitely should not be this way. And does it read values if cells contain numbers?

Comment: Yes, if the cell doesn't have a formula it gives the correct value, otherwise nan

Comment: @Ines what version of pandas are you using I am unable to reproduce in `0.23.3` but it does look like you're using pandas >= 0.21.0

Comment: @Chris I'm using pandas 0.22.0

Comment: Can you provide a small excel file sample and expected results?

Answer (score 3):

@Naga kiran if you want to see the value instead of the formula you can add:

```
wb = load_workbook('empty_book.xlsx', data_only=True)
```

But openpyxl never evaluates formula (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-formulae)

You need to open the empty_book.xlsx with Excel and save it if you want to see the formula result

Answer (score 0):

This question is a quite stale but I didn't find another one that explicitly answer's the OP's question. Assuming you're opening a `.xlsx` file and not a `.xls`, you can do:

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=excel_path, data_only=True)
data = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl')
```

Note that [pandas reads .xls files with xlrd](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html?highlight=storage_options#excel-files), and I'm not sure what the best way to achieve the same thing with that library would be.